# Simple Django Form POST - Not posting

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am fairly new to Django, and programming in general, and I am attempting to increment an IntegerField up by one, every time someone clicks a button from the template.  I have researched this for about 10 hours (I know, ridiculous) with no luck... I'm thinking it is just something extremely simple that I have just looked over. I thought I had solved it with either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431822/django-how-to-increment-integer-field-from-user-input) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995975/django-views-and-forms-submit-button-update-database) question, but I still couldn't get it.

Here is my template (which I am using to {% include %} in a separate template):

```
{% block body %}
<form method="post" action="/vote/">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="endorsers" value="Endorse" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Models.py:

```
class IdeaID(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    endorsers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    contributors = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    backers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My url is set up like this:

```
url(r'^vote/$', 'ideaMachine.views.vote'),
```

And Views.py:

```
@login_required
def vote(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST') and ("endorsers" in request.POST):
        idea_list = request.POST.getlist('ideaid')

        for idea in idea_list:
            ideaVote = IdeaID.objects.get(pk=idea)
            ideaVote.endorsers += 1
            ideaVote.save()
    return render_to_response(
        'vote_success.html', RequestContext(request)
    )
```

From django's dev server, I am getting a "'POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1' 200 58". I'm not sure if that helps solve my problem. The post is not actually updating my endorsers field like I am wanting, but *is* sending me to the vote_success.html, successfully. I'm lost at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Are you ever posting the ideaid? From the looks of it you are submitting an empty form so idea_list never gets anything (this line: `idea_list = request.POST.getlist('ideaid')` )

Comment: Yes, My question is same as Jeff... Have u posting the any values for "ideaid", which you are trying to get in your view?

Comment: Very weird description. The form is clearly posting, since your django server is showing POST request. If you are not seeing any changes in database, then 1) Check if you are even getting past the condition. You can do it by raising error there, or if you have more time - add logging and log something into file there. 2) Like Jeff said, see if idea_list contains something or not.

Comment: Wow you guys are quick! Sorry if I was pretty vague, it's my first stackoverflow post.  You all were correct, the form wasn't actually doing anything. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to implement a functionality which allows endorsement of different users.

Here is how you could modify the code to make it work:

in the vote.html template modify to:

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/">{% csrf_token %}
{% for ideaid in ideaids %}
    <li>{{ ideaid.user }} - {{ ideaid.endorsers }}
    <input type="checkbox" name="ideaid" value="{{ ideaid.id }}" /></li><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="endorsers" value="Endorse" />
</form>
```

I assume that vote_success.html looks something like

```
{% for ideaid in ideaids %}
    <li>{{ ideaid.user }} - {{ ideaid.endorsers }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then you could modify views.py

- Use render(request, instead of render_to_response
- Populate ideaids in the context with data from IdeaID
- Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a user hits the Back button.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import Context, RequestContext, loader
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

def vote(request):

    if (request.method == 'POST') and ("endorsers" in request.POST):
        idea_list = request.POST.getlist('ideaid')

        for idea in idea_list:
            ideaVote = IdeaID.objects.get(pk=idea)
            ideaVote.endorsers += 1
            ideaVote.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ideaMachine.views.vote_success', args=()))

    ideaid = IdeaID.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vote.html', {'ideaids':ideaid})

def vote_success(request):
    ideaid = IdeaID.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'vote_success.html', {'ideaids':ideaid})
```

You need also one more entry in urls:

```
    url(r'^success/$', 'ideaMachine.views.vote_success'),
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I believe my main problem was in the form.  Very informative post, thanks for that. I'm still trying to grasp all of this :/